# How to upgrade an existing sqlite database to a newer version of sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have an existing sqllite database created using version 3.13. 
I want to be able to use window functions like Row_number and those functions are supported by version 3.25.0 or higher. So how do i upgrade my existing db?

Comment: You "just" need to upgrade your SQLite driver. The database file format remains unchanged between all SQLite 3 versions.